# Showing all rows for keys with more than one row

Tags: mysql, join, in-subquery

```
Table kal
id integer primary key
init char 4 indexed
job char4

id  init job
--+----+------
1 | aa | job1
2 | aa | job2
3 | bb | job1
4 | cc | job3   
5 | cc | job5
```

I want to show all rows where init has more than one row:

```
id  init job
--+----+------
1 | aa | job1
2 | aa | job2
4 | cc | job3   
5 | cc | job5
```

I tried:

```
select * from kal where init in (select init from kal group by init having 
count(init)>2);
```

Actually, the table has 60000 rows, and the query was

```
count(init)<40,
```

but it takes a humongous amount of time, phpmyadmin and my patience runs out.

Both

```
select init from kal group by init having count(init)>2)
```

and

```
select * from kal where init in ('aa','bb','cc')
```

runs in "no time", less than 0.02 seconds.

I've tried different subqueries, but all takes "infinite" time, more than a few minutes; I've actually never let them finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, and you can [see it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ac49/1) in action:

**Query**

```
SELECT a.id, a.init, a.job
FROM kal a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT init, COUNT(init) 
  FROM kal
  GROUP BY init
  HAVING COUNT(init) > 1) b ON b.init = a.init
```

**Result**

```
| ID | INIT |  JOB |
--------------------
|  1 |   aa | job1 |
|  2 |   aa | job2 |
|  4 |   cc | job3 |
|  5 |   cc | job5 |
```

Comment: Great! My query went from "infinite" time to 0.0982 sec on 50.000 records. I'd vote up, if I could. :-) Btw, the inner SELECT could just be SELECT init FROM kal. The important thing here is that the subselect have its own alias, "b" after the ")", not inside. And I wish I could format this...

Comment: @LeifNeland You can modify the fiddle and I can update the code to reflect a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `EXISTS`?

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where exists (select count(*)
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.init = t2.init
              group by t2.init
              having count(*) >= 2);
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d1fb/9)

Or even this:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select count(*) cnt, init
  from yourtable
  group by init
) t2
  on t1.init = t2.init
where t2.cnt > 1
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d1fb/12)